# How to use ioctl with SIOCGIWESSID

Tags: rust, ioctl

I want to read the SSID that I'm connect to.
I'm using ioctl to do so. I'm trying to read it using `nix::ioctl_read`.
I'm new to this so I'm unsure if what I'm doing is correct.
Here's what I've tried.

```
const SIOCGIWESSID: u8 = 0x8B;
ioctl_read!(read_essid, SIOCGIWESSID, 0x8B1B, Iwreq);

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Essid {
    length: u8,
    pointer: [u8; 33],
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct WreqData {
    essid: Essid,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
#[repr(C)]
pub struct Iwreq {
    frn_name: [u8; 33],
    u: WreqData,
}

fn get_essid() -> String {
    const WESSID_LEN: usize = 33;
    let fd = socket(
        AddressFamily::Inet,
        SockType::Datagram,
        SockFlag::empty(),
        None,
    )
    .unwrap();
    let pointer: [u8; WESSID_LEN] = [0; WESSID_LEN];
    let mut ifr_tmp = [0u8; WESSID_LEN];
    let interface_name = "wlp2s0\0";
    ifr_tmp[..interface_name.len()].copy_from_slice(interface_name.as_bytes());
    let mut data = Iwreq {
        frn_name: ifr_tmp,
        u: WreqData {
            essid: Essid {
                length: WESSID_LEN as u8,
                pointer,
            },
        },
    };
    println!("{}", unsafe { read_essid(fd, &mut data).unwrap() });
    println!("{:?}", data);
    unimplemented!()
}
```

I get the error "ENOTTY" from the ioctl call. I think I'm passing incorrect arguments to ioctl_read.
What can I pass to `ioctl_read!` to make it work? Or is there another solution I should be looking into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have two main problems:

- Your structs don't accurately represent the Linux kernel's expected input data format (e.g. see the `struct iwreq` definition from the latest mainline `v6.5` release: [`include/uapi/linux/wireless.h`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/wireless.h?h=v6.5#n939))
- The wireless subsystem `ioctl` numbers don't follow the newer convention. They instead use arbitrary hardcoded numbers. The `nix` crate documentation refers to these as [*bad* `ioctl`s](https://docs.rs/nix/0.27.1/nix/sys/ioctl/index.html#using-bad-ioctls). You can therefore instead use the [`ioctl_read_bad!`](https://docs.rs/nix/0.27.1/nix/macro.ioctl_read_bad.html) macro

Here is a modified version that appears to work on my machine:

```
#[repr(C)]
pub struct Essid {
    pointer: *const c_char,
    length: u16,
    flags: u16,
}

impl Essid {
    const fn new(pointer: *const c_char) -> Self {
        Self {
            pointer,
            length: 33,
            flags: 0,
        }
    }
}

#[repr(C)]
pub struct WreqData {
    essid: Essid,
}

#[repr(C)]
pub struct Iwreq {
    frn_name: [u8; 16],
    u: WreqData,
}

impl Iwreq {
    fn new(name: &str, buf: &[c_char; 33]) -> Self {
        let mut frn_name = [0; 16];
        frn_name[..name.len()].copy_from_slice(name.as_bytes());

        Self {
            frn_name,
            u: WreqData {
                essid: Essid::new(buf.as_ptr()),
            },
        }
    }
}

nix::ioctl_read_bad!(read_essid, 0x8B1B, Iwreq);

fn get_essid(name: &str) -> anyhow::Result<String> {
    let sock = socket::socket(
        AddressFamily::Inet,
        SockType::Datagram,
        SockFlag::empty(),
        None,
    )?;
    let buf = [0; 33];
    let mut data = Iwreq::new(name, &buf);
    unsafe { read_essid(sock.as_raw_fd(), &mut data) }?;
    let ptr = buf.as_ptr();
    Ok(unsafe { CStr::from_ptr(ptr) }.to_str()?.to_owned())
}
```

Alternatively, the same information could be obtained using netlink sockets. For example:

```
async fn get_essid(name: &str) -> anyhow::Result<String> {
    let (connection, handle, _) = wl_nl80211::new_connection()?;
    tokio::spawn(connection);

    let mut ifaces = handle.interface().get().execute().await;
    while let Ok(Some(iface)) = ifaces.try_next().await {
        if !iface
            .payload
            .nlas
            .iter()
            .any(|nla| matches!(nla, Nl80211Attr::IfName(n) if n == name))
        {
            continue;
        }

        for nla in iface.payload.nlas {
            if let Nl80211Attr::Ssid(ssid) = nla {
                return Ok(ssid);
            }
        }
    }

    bail!("SSID not found")
}
```

I've uploaded this example/test code to GitLab if you want to look at it in full: https://gitlab.com/harryausten/ssid-query. Hope this helps!